Print code did not print. ASM x64 NASM/LD/WINDOWS
I was trying to follow a tutorial on how to print a sentence. It didnt work.
I'm using:

GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.43.1

NASM version 2.16.03

x64 Windows


To compile the assembly file I'm doing:
nasm -f win64 -o main.obj main.asm

ld -o main.exe main.obj

But when I do .\main.exe in the cmd is does nothing, Why is that?
section .data
    hello: db "Hello, World", 10
    helloLen: equ $-hello


section .text
    global _start

_start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, hello
        mov rdx, helloLen
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall


You’re attempting to run an assembly program designed for Linux on Windows. It won’t work. Try building and running it under WSL if you want to see something.

Assembly is different for each assembler, operating system and CPU architecture.  You must find a tutorial that matches the assembler, operating system, and architecture you are programming for.

Why did you add this to review?  The linked duplicates already answer it.  If you want to know exactly what your code did when run under Windows, look up call numbers 1 and 60 on https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/ for your kernel version to find out which raw system calls you invoked.
